# Fix JSON Parsing Scale Imageview tableview

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I build project tableview with Json parsing. My project its work, but my imageview is spread. Before I already setting constraint for it image

Can someone help me how to make image to scale fit with constraint setting

**My code**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    final let urlString = "http://wisatasumbar.esy.es/restful/search_articles.php?&keyword=bukittinggi"

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var wisataArr = [String]()
    var titleArr = [String]()
    var imgUrlArr = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.downloadJsonWithURL()

    }

    func downloadJsonWithURL () {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {

                print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "data"))

                if let dataArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "data") as? NSArray {
                    for data in dataArray{
                        if let dataDict = data as? NSDictionary{
                            if let title = dataDict.value(forKey: "title"){
                                self.titleArr.append(title as! String)
                            }
                            if let title = dataDict.value(forKey: "category"){
                                self.wisataArr.append(title as! String)
                            }
                            if let title = dataDict.value(forKey: "image_satu"){
                                self.imgUrlArr.append(title as! String)
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                })
            }

        }).resume()
    }

    func downloadJsonWitTask () {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        var downloadTask = URLRequest(url: (url as? URL)!, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 20)

        downloadTask.httpMethod = "GET"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadTask, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)

            print(jsonObj)

        }).resume()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titleArr.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell

        cell.lblTitle.text! = titleArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblWisata.text! = wisataArr[indexPath.row]

        let imgUrl = NSURL(string: imgUrlArr[indexPath.row])

        if imgUrl != nil {
            let data = NSData(contentsOf: imgUrl as! URL)
            cell.imgView.image = UIImage(data: data as! Data)
        }
        return cell

    }

}
```

and this my app:

[View Project Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp29D.jpg)

Comment: use `clipsToBound` to true for imageview property

Comment: i do, but my project not works. juts white table

Comment: still spread. omg, what this problemm

Comment: @Menda Can you add your `ImageView` Constraints

Comment: @agent_stack i do. but not works

Comment: @Menda If you don't add constraint images then I can't help you. And if you unable to add image in your question then write down which constraints you have given to the imageView